# When HeapCreate function is used or in what cases do you need a number of heaps?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-management

Windows API has a set of function for heap creation and handling: HeapCreate, HeapAlloc, HeapDestroy and etc.
I wonder what is the use for another heap in a program? 
From fragmentation point of view, you will get external fragmentation where memory is not reused among heaps. So even if low-fragmentation heaps are used, stil there is a fragmentation.
Memory management of additional heaps seems to be low-level. So they are not easy to use.
In addition, additional heap can probably be emulated using allocations from heap and managing allocated memory.

So what is the usage? Did you use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One use case might be a long-running complex process that does a lot of memory allocation and deallocation. If the user wants to interrupt the process, then an easy way to clean up the memory currently allocated might be to have everything on a private heap and then simply destroy the heap.

I have seen this technique used in an embedded system (which wasn't using Windows, so it didn't use those exact API functions). The custom memory allocator had a feature to "mark" a specific state of the heap and then "rewind" to that point if a process was aborted.

Answer (score 4):

One reason that is only important in rare situations, but immensely important there: memory allocated by `new/malloc` isn't executable on modern Windows systems. Hence if you write for example a JIT, you will have to use `HeapCreate` with `HEAP_CREATE_ENABLE_EXECUTE`.

Answer (score 3):

Use: Very very very rarily.

Usage:
I once worked on a projected that used the heap management as a crude garbage collector (no destructors). There was a section of the code that went off a did some work without regard to memory management (using a separate heap). Then when it was done we just destroyed that heap to re-claim all the memory.

Answer (score 2):

One use is for fixed size objects. If you need to do a lot of allocation/deallocation of objects that are all the same size (i.e. small message buffers) a private heap avoids fragmentation issues.

Comment: ie you use the low-fragmenetation heap, which is also much faster.

Answer (score 1):

You might also dedicate a heap per thread - for locality of reference or to reduce locking (which is required when a heap is shared across threads).

Answer (score 0):

One use case I see more often than not is in malware.

The malware would have a packed binary somewhere in its `.rsrc` section, allocate an executable private heap, and then run the code there. Its a *very* effective technique

Answer (score 0):

One usage not mentioned here is to [avoid heap contention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1x2sk32.aspx).
You could create a thread-local heap which is not thread-safe, passing `HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE` flag to [`HeapCreate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366599(v=vs.85).aspx).
Since only one thread can access the heap, no locks are required and contention is alleviated.

Comment: HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE blocks LFH feature, i think it's better to create private heap without HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE but with LFH.

Comment: Details about LFH and HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983563/reason-for-100x-slowdown-with-heap-memory-functions-using-heap-no-serialize-on)